# Orthogonality in Space of Polynomials of Degree at Most 2

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products, orthogonal-polynomials, orthogonality

Let $E$ be the space of polynomials of degree at most $2$. On $E$ define $\langle f,g \rangle := f(-1)\overline{g(-1)}+f(0)\overline{g(0)}+f(1)\overline{g(1)}$ for $f,g \in E$.

a). Show that this defines an inner product on $E$.

b). Describe $\{t^2-1\}^{\perp}$.

c). Show that the polynomials $t^2-1, t^2-t$ are orthogonal, and find a nonzero polynomial $p \in E$ that is orthogonal to both of them.

For the first part, I believe I was able to satisfy the 4 properties required as per my textbook:

1. Sesquilinear: $\langle \lambda f+ \mu g, h \rangle = \lambda \langle f,h \rangle + \mu \langle g, h \rangle$.
2. Symmetric: $\langle f,g \rangle = \overline{\langle g, f \rangle}, \quad f,g \in E$.
3. Positive: $\langle f, f \rangle \geq 0.$
4. Definite: $\langle f,f \rangle = 0 \Rightarrow f = 0$.

I didn't want to include the details of this in order to save some space on this post. What I am struggling on is parts (b) and (c).

For (b), I have that $\{t^2-1\}^{\perp} = \{f \in E: f \perp g \forall g \in \{t^2-1\} \}$. This would mean that the orthogonal compliment of $\{t^2-1\}$ is the set of all polynomials of degree at most 2 whose inner product with $g \in \{t^2-1\}$ is equal to 0. However, is this an accurate enough description or is it too general?

For (c), using the inner product defined on $E$, I have the following:

I rewrote the inner product as $\langle f,g \rangle = \sum_{i=-1}^{1} f(i)\overline{g(i)} = \left. t^2-t\overline{(t^2-1)}\right|_{-1} + \left. t^2-\overline{t(t^2-1)}\right|_0 + \left. t^2-t\overline{(t^2-1)}\right|_1$. Since I have to use the conjugate of $t^2-1$, then I change that term to $t^2+1$ and then evaluate. But I got a value of 4 which implies that $f=t^2-t$ and $g=t^2-1$ are not orthogonal. Was there something wrong with my calculation? As for the next part, I have not gotten there yet, but I assume that I would have to do some sort of long division first.

As always, any help/suggestions/advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance. I am using the textbook *Functional Analysis An Elementary Introduction* by Markus Haase.

Comment: Concerning b). The description is to rough. Could you provide a basis of the orthogonal complEment? Concerning c) The conjugate does not change  - into +. It changes $-i$ to $+i$.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 In order to provide a basis, would the Gram-Schmidt procedure suffice? If so, what set of basis elements should I choose?                                                            For (c), the $i$ is the index of the summation. So the conjugate would change the $g(i)$ into $g(-i)$? I thought that I would use $g=t^2-1$ in the calculation, so what changes when the conjugate is applied? Thank you very much for your response, I have been struggling with this problem for a few days now and really want to finish it.

Comment: no, only the $t^2$ is conjugated. You seem to consider complex polynomials, thus $t\in\mathbb{C}$, so you only have $\bar{t}^2$. Then you see directly, that $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal. A simple basis of you space are the vectors $1,t,t^2$. Try to find a linear combination that is orthogonal on $t^2-t$ and $t^2-1$.

Comment: Ok, so if the conjugate changes $t^2-1$ into $t^{-2}-1$, then wouldn't there be an issue with  the evaluation of the inner product at the value of 0?

Comment: let $z$ be a complex number, what is $\bar{z^2}$? and furthermore $\bar 0=0$. Maybe you misread my comment?

Comment: I apologize, I believe I did misread $\overline{t}^2$ for $t^{-2}$. If $z$ is a complex number in the form $a+bi,$ then $\overline{z} = a-bi, \quad a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: so there will be no issue when evaluation in $t=0$ :)

Comment: After some calculations, I believe I was able to show that $t^2-1$ and $t^2-t$ are orthogonal only if the constant term is equal to zero. So a better description of $\{t^2-1\}^{\perp}$ is the set of polynomials of degree at most 2 whose constant term is zero. With this in mind, how may I utilize the simple basis suggested in order to solve part (c)?

Comment: this is not yet a precise description. What is a third basis vector of the space?

Comment: third basis vector? If the simple basis is $1,t,t^2$, then wouldn't the third one be $t^2$? Maybe I am not understanding your question. Thank you very much for your patience and assistance.

Comment: So  you want to find the space that is orthogonal on the linear space spanned by $t^2-1$. You checked that $t^2-t$ is orthogonal on this space. Thus $t^2-t$ is one basis vector of the orthogonal complement of $t^2-1$. Can you find another vector that is orthogonal on $t^2-1$ and linearly independent of $t^2-t$? Then you have a basis of the orthogonal complement. By the way, could you add the tag (linear-algebra) I think this tag fits better than functional analysis.

Comment: Would $t^3-t^2$ suffice? Sorry for replying so late, I had other assignments to work on and am barely getting back to this one. Also, I included the Linear Algebra tag :)

Comment: $t^3$ is not in your space